# How to get chart data in tabular form same as 'view data table' on click a button

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have a chart in highcharts I need to get the data in tabular form same as 'view data table' when I click a button.I need to capture the data from same highchart.Is there any method of highchart so that I can capture the data in tabular form.Can any one please help me.Here is the code below

### HTML

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>  
    <button class="chart1">chart1</button>
    <div id="chart1"></div>
```

### Javasvript

```
Highcharts.chart('chart1', {

    title: {
        text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            label: {
                connectorAllowed: false
            },
            pointStart: 2010
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }, {
        name: 'Manufacturing',
        data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
    }, {
        name: 'Sales & Distribution',
        data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
    }, {
        name: 'Project Development',
        data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
    }, {
        name: 'Other',
        data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
    }],

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        }]
    }

});
```

Comment: Why you don't want to use highcharts table? Check `chart.getDataRows()` method. Api: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#getDataRows , demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k57r362o/1/

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to hide & display table on clicking on the button ? if yes, then this would help you

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<button class="chart1" id='ch1'>chart1</button>
<div id="chart1"></div>

<button class="chart2" id='ch2'>chart2</button>
<div id="chart2"></div>
```

**Highcharts**

```
    var chart = Highcharts.chart('chart1', {

title: {
    text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
},

subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
},

yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Number of Employees'
    }
},
legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'middle'
},

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        label: {
            connectorAllowed: false
        },
        pointStart: 2010
    }
},

series: [{
    name: 'Installation',
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
}, {
    name: 'Manufacturing',
    data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
}, {
    name: 'Sales & Distribution',
    data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
}, {
    name: 'Project Development',
    data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
}, {
    name: 'Other',
    data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
}],
exporting: {
    showTable: true
},
responsive: {
    rules: [{
        condition: {
            maxWidth: 500
        },
        chartOptions: {
            legend: {
                layout: 'horizontal',
                align: 'center',
                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }
        }
    }]
    }

});
var chart2 = Highcharts.chart('chart2', {

title: {
    text: 'test data'
},

subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
},

yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Number of Employees'
    }
},
legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'middle'
},

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        label: {
            connectorAllowed: false
        },
        pointStart: 2010
    }
},

series: [{
    name: 'Installation',
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
}, {
    name: 'Manufacturing',
    data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
}],
exporting: {
    showTable: true
},
responsive: {
    rules: [{
        condition: {
            maxWidth: 500
        },
        chartOptions: {
            legend: {
                layout: 'horizontal',
                align: 'center',
                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }
        }
    }]
}

});

$('#ch1').click(function() {
var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('highcharts-data-table')[0];

if (!ele.style.display) {
    ele.style.display = 'none'
} else {
    ele.style.display = ''
}


});

$('#ch2').click(function() {
var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('highcharts-data-table')[1];

if (!ele.style.display) {
    ele.style.display = 'none'
} else {
    ele.style.display = ''
}

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/karnan796/m871Lbz4/53/

Comment: Thanks for your answer actually I do not want to use the inbult function of highchart,I want to capture the data manually from highcharts and loop into a table so that its look like showTable in highcharts